# How can I redirect output of die function to a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, die, perl-io

I want to redirect the `die` messages to a separate file so that I can compare that file later to determine what went wrong.

But this code gives me errors:

```
$ cat test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $log = "msglog.log";
die $log "DEAD$!";

$ perl test.pl
Missing comma after first argument to die function at test.pl line 5, near ""DEAD$!";"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
$
```

I do not want to do a `2>` from the caller. Is there someway to redirect them from within the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl's `die` prints to `STDERR` so you could redirect `STDERR` to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# the path above depends on your system

open(STDERR, ">>", "errlog.log");
die "Hello";
```

Comment: This also redirects warn() messages, warnings, and anything else printed to STDERR. Not only that, if someone has done this properly by redefining the __DIE__ handler, it might not even redirect die() messages.

Answer (score 15):

You can install a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler to be run just before the "die" runs. The handler will be called with the error message which you can log:

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ($message) = @_;
    # log the message        
};
```

See [$SIG{expr}](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24SIG%7bexpr%7d) in perlvar for details.

Answer (score 10):

The [`Log::Log4perl`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm) module offers more than a few options.

One can choose to output the error message to both STDERR and the logfile.

```
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->init ( 'log.conf' );
# Configuration file controls what to output, like time, line number, class...

$logger->get_logger ( 'Hello::World' );  # Define which class logger to use

.
.
.

open my $fh, '<', $file
  or $logger->logdie ( "Log the demise: $!" );  # ... and die;
```

While it requires a little bit more effort in terms of setup, its flexibility unlocks a great deal of potential.